Looking for a young adult fantasy book about a girl who is half faerie and can use magic from all five elements?
I am trying to find a book that I once read about a girl who thinks she is half-faerie(and I think also royal), where her mom was a faerie(but passed away) and her dad, who she thinks is human, who is a powerful man in the human world. She enrols to this school and befriends a group of powerful faeries, and I think she becomes close to this guy, who I remember was a rockstar? She also has an affinity to all five elements. Does anyone know of a book with a similar description??

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you give us a better idea approximately when you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover?

https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/46040795 this sort of nonsense is pretty comment and tropey. Can you be more specific?

https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9792199

Is it set in the modern world with a "masquerade", or a modern-ish world similar to the real one but with magic known about generally, or something else?
